# Sonicwall TZ 180 VLAN Trunking

Tags: vlan, sonicwall

I was just wondering if the Sonicwall TZ 180 supports VLAN Trunking, and if so do I need SonicOS Enhanced?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does support VLANs but not the all range:

http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/DataSheet-TZ_Series-US-TD-567.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the TZ180 (or any devices of that TZ generation) support VLANs on Standard or Enhanced firmware.  But please confirm with Sonicwall tech support.